# generate permutation from partition of numeric

Tags: r, list, permutation, partition

i will generate permutations of a partitions.
i generate partitions with this code:
library(partitions)

```
x <- c(2,4,6)       
parts <- listParts(length(x))
out <- rapply(parts, function(ii) x[ii], how="replace")
```

and generate

out

```
[[1]]
[1] (2,4,6)

[[2]]
[1] (2,6)(4)

[[3]]
[1] (2,4)(6)

[[4]]
[1] (4,6)(2)

[[5]]
[1] (2)(4)(6)
```

take a element for example `[1](2)(4)(6)` i would generate all possible permutations. I tried  with:

```
 library(combinat)
 permn(x)
```

but the return element is not in the same form of input,for example with element
`[1](21,33,41,40,39,3,6)(13,37)`  return:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$`1`
[1] 21 33 41 40 39  3  6

[[1]]$`2`
[1] 13 37


[[2]]
[[2]]$`2`
[1] 13 37

[[2]]$`1`
[1] 21 33 41 40 39  3  6
```

i do similar question some week ago, but the solution that was given to when generate partitions generate permutations for all possible partitions, but for problem of 
efficiency i can't use it.
the solution this was it:

```
library(partitions)
permListParts <- function (x) 
{
    f <- function(pp) {
        out <- split(seq_along(pp), pp)
        myPerms <- perms(length(out))
        apply(myPerms, 2, function(x) {
            temp <- out[x]
            class(temp) <- c(class(temp), "equivalence")
            temp
        })
    }
    apply(setparts(x), 2, f)}
```